# How to create a POST request to store file on server from local path - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, post, fetch-api

I am trying to save a pdf file from the local device to my server using a REST Service in React Native. In my case, when I click on "SAVE" button the file is stored in a temp file path which I want to simultaneously save on my server.

```js
 <View style={styles.button}>
                            <Button
                                onPress={() => {
                                    // Save Document
                                    this._viewer.saveDocument().then((filePath) => {
                                        console.info('saveDocument:', filePath);
                                      });
                                }}
                                title="Save"
                            />
                        </View>
```

The filePath is a temp path - 'saveDocument:', '/data/user/0/nativetemplate/cache/Test.pdf'
I want to upload this file to the server. I am new to React Native and I am confused about the implementation.
I know I should use fetch(), but should I call a separate method to do that? How do I trigger this action simultaneously with the button onPress action?

```js
fetch('https://example.com/data', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    filePath: '/data/user/0/nativetemplate/cache/Test.pdf',
  })
});
```

I actually want to send the file contents to update the file on server, can I send the temp (cache) file path directly or I need to retrieve the file first from the cache? If so, How do I retrieve the file from this path?

Comment: You should have to use multipart/form-data to send file to server using api call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FormData to upload file on server

```
const file = {
    uri : filePath,
    type : fileType,
    name : filename
  }
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('filePath', file) // filePath -> your param for the file
```

Then Make server call

```
const response = await fetch(serverurl, {
    method: "POST",
    body:formData
  })
```